# Flask Form.validate_on_submit not redirecting

Tags: python, flask

I am in the process of learning the flask framework and as such Im writing a blog. I am working on the register function but Im not getting it to redirect

Here is the route for registration

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm

@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Account Created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    return render_template('register.html', title="Register", form=form)
```

And this is the form tag that Im using for the register.html
`<form method="POST" action="">`

I ran through debugging and it is skipping right over the if statement. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed please let me know!

Comment: `form.validate_on_submit()` will only return true if the form is valid. Are there any errors on the form? Try looking at `form.errors`, which will show you why the validation failed.

Comment: So Im looking through the errors in the debugger and its just an empty dictionary. No errors are being reported

Comment: It's an empty dictionary when the form is posted, *after* validate_on_submit is called?? Can you post a full example I can reproduce? That can't be right.

Comment: Im so sorry. I was being stupid. The error is ["Invalid field name 'Password'."]

Comment: No worries. You'll want to make sure and show the user any errors in the form. [Here's some example code to show a form field and show any errors belonging to it](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates), it might be helpful.

Comment: Ok. I will definately be adding errors to be presented to the user that but now Im trying to understand what field its talking about when its calling a field name invalid. Im looking through my code and Im not seeing a field name that is Password'."

Comment: I'm assuming `password` is on the `RegistrationForm` class. But I can't say without seeing a testable example.

Comment: After reading through your comment I understood where the error is.
'''
password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
 confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo("password")])''' I had Equalto("password") set with a capital P. Thank you for talking through this with me. I will definately be reading through the link you sent

Answer (score 0):

It was the gap in my understanding of how EqualTo works
(This is in the forms code)

```
password = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo("password")])
```

I had the P in the Parentheses capitalized and thus is was returning an error of unknown field

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into same problem.
And solved by checking the forms.py in my project. Which i've put all the forms in the same file.

my mistake is in here:

```
*password* = PasswordField("Password", validators=[DataRequired()])
confirm_password = PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo("*Password*")])
```

So as i understand, the parameter of `EqualTo(parameter)` is must be the variable name of the PasswordField.

Solution to my problem was the change the case of the P.